# Find the volume of the body bounded by $y=4-x^2,y=2x+1,z=1,z=2+x^2+y^2$

Tags: calculus

I am new to volume of bounded bodies and I am struggling with the problem in the title.

I know I have to do this:

$\iint_D\ z_2(x,y)-z_1(x,z)\,dx\,dy$

So I have just done this:

$\iint_D\ [2+x^2+y^2]-[1]\,dx\,dy$

Now I´m struggling with the D in this case. I don´t get what the region D would be. Do I have to consider the paraboloid to find D? and if this is the case how do I write the limits of each integral?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the easiest way to find this out is to draw the graphs of the bounds and figure out what is inside and what is outside. However, in this particular case, we may nail down bounds for $z$ immediately.

So, we have the bounds for $z$ determined by $z=1$ and $z=2+x^2+y^2$. But, if you examine carefully, you will see that $2+x^2+y^2\geq 2$ and thus it only makes sense that $$1\leq z \leq 2+x^2+y^2.$$

With $z$ out of our way, we can focus on $x$ and $y$ and our problem becomes 2-dimensional, easy to sketch. So, draw the parabola and the line in $xy$ plane and find intersections by setting $$4-x^2 = 2x+1.$$
This gives us bounds for both $x$ and $y$, namely, $-3\leq x\leq 1$ and $2x+1\leq y \leq 4-x^2.$

Your volume then becomes

$$V=\int_{-3}^1\int_{2x+1}^{4-x^2}\int_1^{2+x^2+y^2}1\,dz\,dy\,dx.$$

If you eliminate $z$, it becomes $$V=\int_{-3}^1\int_{2x+1}^{4-x^2}((2+x^2+y^2)-1)\,dy\,dx,$$

the integral you wrote yourself (up to the region $D$).

Comment: @Arthur, make sure that you sketch and understand how the bounds for $x$ and $y$ that I wrote work. If you are having trouble with it, let me know.